# Javascript and Arrays

Tags: javascript, highcharts

This i have to admin has always been my Achilles tendon despite my years of experience in programming.

I have a json result looking like this from which I want to draw a time series using highcharts.com

```
[{"iso-2":"DE","year":"2000","value":"0"},{"iso-2":"FR","year":"2000","value":"0"},{"iso-2":"KE","year":"2000","value":"0"},{"iso-2":"DE","year":"2001","value":"0"},{"iso-2":"FR","year":"2001","value":"0"},{"iso-2":"KE","year":"2001","value":"0"},{"iso-2":"DE","year":"2002","value":"0"},{"iso-2":"FR","year":"2002","value":"0"},{"iso-2":"KE","year":"2002","value":"0"},{"iso-2":"DE","year":"2003","value":"9355"},{"iso-2":"FR","year":"2003","value":"19490"},{"iso-2":"KE","year":"2003","value":"0"},{"iso-2":"DE","year":"2004","value":"0"},{"iso-2":"FR","year":"2004","value":"0"},{"iso-2":"KE","year":"2004","value":"0"},{"iso-2":"DE","year":"2005","value":"11"},{"iso-2":"FR","year":"2005","value":"8"},{"iso-2":"KE","year":"2005","value":"0"},{"iso-2":"DE","year":"2006","value":"2"},{"iso-2":"FR","year":"2006","value":"1388"},{"iso-2":"KE","year":"2006","value":"0"},{"iso-2":"DE","year":"2007","value":"0"},{"iso-2":"FR","year":"2007","value":"0"},{"iso-2":"KE","year":"2007","value":"0"}]
```

I'd like to dynamically generate the above result into an arrays that looks like this

```
series: [{
            name: 'KE',
            data: [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
        }, {
            name: 'FR',
            data: [0,0,0,19490,0,8,1388,0]
        }, {
            name: 'DE',
            data: [0,0,0,9355,0,2,0]
        }]
```

Thank you so much for looking into this

Comment: possible duplicate of [Array for Highcharts:](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8198422/array-for-highcharts)

Comment: I have written and re-written until my fingers hurt. I'm stuck at the loop for creating the series, i've tried a for loop and using jQuery's filter() and map() functions but the logic isn't just coming out. I've checked the link but we're drawing slightly something different but experimenting with the answer. Thanks for writing

Comment: I am sure :) What I wanted to say is that some code will help more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I can think of, considering the data you have in the JSON is sorted by year:

```
var json_data = '[{"iso-2":"DE","year":"2000","value":"0"},...]'; // This is the json data you have.
var data = JSON.parse(json_data); // Convert JSON data to javascript object or array

// Organize the data in an object
var organized = {};

data.forEach(function (item){
    if (typeof organized[item['iso-2']] !== 'undefined'){
        organized[item['iso-2']].push(item['value']);
    } else {
        organized[item['iso-2']] = [item['value']];
    }
});

// Convert the object to the format you need
var series = [];

for (i in organized){
    series.push({
        name: i,
        data: organized[i]
    });
}
```

Comment: Also works like a charm. No need to convert to Json as in line 2 because it is already json. I like your solution because i don't need to add extra js

Answer (score 2):

```
var gathered = data.reduce(function(prev, curr) {
    if (prev.hasOwnProperty(curr["iso-2"])) {
        prev[curr["iso-2"]].push(parseInt(curr["value"]));
    } else {
        prev[curr["iso-2"]] = [parseInt(curr["value"])];
    }
    return prev;
}, {});

var result = [];
for (var country in gathered) {
    var obj = {};
    obj["name"] = country;
    obj["data"] = gathered[country];
    result.push(obj);
}

console.log(result);
```

**Output**

```
[ { name: 'DE', data: [ 0, 0, 0, 9355, 0, 11, 2, 0 ] },
  { name: 'FR', data: [ 0, 0, 0, 19490, 0, 8, 1388, 0 ] },
  { name: 'KE', data: [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ] } ]
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I'd have a case of beer delivered at your door if I had your address!